# How do you pronounce $\preceq$?

Tags: terminology, relations

I've been reading about partial orders and partially ordered sets and have come across sentences like "Suppose that $\preceq$ is a partial order on $X$" and "If $x\preceq y$ and $y \preceq z$ then $x \preceq z$ for $x,y,z \in X$".

How do you pronounce the symbol $\preceq$ in these cases?

Comment: Just "Less than or equal". if you have both $\leq$ and the curly one, you invent some convenction with the person you are talking with to tell them apart, like calling "curly less than or equal". Sometimes $\preceq$ is called "preceeds", but that only makes sense in some contexts.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't have its own name as such? Because $\leq$ is a specific example of $\preceq$ isn't it?

Comment: @Mariano I like "precedes", when there's nothing else available.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context.

If there is no ambiguity, "less than or equal to" works.

In a lecture, you might pronounce it "curly less than" to help people who are taking notes. If you want a short way to pronounce it, you might vocally label it "r" or "rel" (short for "relation"), as in "Suppose that rel is a partial order", but this is less standard and I would personally say "Suppose that curly-less-than is a partial order; I will call it 'rel' from now on".

Comment: Vrijheid van spreken is great!

Comment: You might get a hint from the way you write this symbol in TeX: \prec (and \preceq) precedes, \succ (\succeq) succeeds (or might use "follows" instead). This need not be a standard approach, but it helps me when I encounter $\le$ and $\preceq$ in the same paper, to keep the two clearer in my head as I read.

Answer (score 1):

"Precedes or is equal to", or in informal contexts "precedes or equals".

Answer (score 0):

In many languages the term translated as "**less or equal to**" is used.

Using "Less than or equal to" is just too much statement to use in daily math equations, so the shorter version is preferred and it sounds much better in some other than English languages. I am not sure which one is used most in English, though, but I thing the shorter version is preferable.